# Writing a python file to an online SQL database

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to take my output from my python code and write it into a chart on an online SQL database. I attempted to use sqlite3 here:

```
def write_sql(index, data):


    conn = sqlite3.connect('tt.db')

    c = conn.cursor()
    #c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IPlist(IP text, Availibility real)''')

    for key in data:    
        print key
        c.execute("INSERT INTO IPlist VALUES (%s,%d)" , (key, data[key]))

    conn.commit()
```

However, I get an operational error and I'm also unsure of how to connect to the online database as opposed to just a local test document.

Comment: How does `data` look like?

Comment: its a dictionary of strings mapped to integers, for example "10.2.35.100" to 1

Comment: SQLite is an embedded database which operates on files. For online stuff, you'll need something else, like Postgres or MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using the standard `sqlite3` library, then you're specifying the parameters to the query incorrectly. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html):

> The sqlite3 module supports two kinds of placeholders: question marks
>   (qmark style) and named placeholders (named style).

You're attempting to use ANSI C printf format codes, which is not supported. Try either of the following:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO IPlist VALUES (?,?)" , (key, data[key]))

c.execute("INSERT INTO IPlist VALUES (:key,:data)" , {"key":key, "data":data[key]})
```